# How does #define work in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define squareOf(x) x*x

int main() {
// your code goes here
int x;
cout<<squareOf(x+4);
return 0;
}
```

I thought the answer would come as 16 but it came out as 4. 
I am confused how does this works.

Comment: `x` is not initialized, this is just *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep hehe correct but please explain this behavior of macros

Comment: @SrishtiMittal macros are pure text replacement, there is no magic here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace - and if you replace `squareOf(x+4)` you do get: `x+4*x+4`

Answer (score 8):

16 would never be the result here. Let's say you would have initialized x with 0, then you would have your x+4 replaced by x+4*x+4 which would evaluate as 0+4*0+4 = 4.

Preprocessor macros *replace* source code, they are *not* functions.

You might now think that maybe

```
#define squareOf(x) (x)*(x)
```

would be better, but consider that then

```
int x = 2;
int y = squareOf(x++);
```

would result in y = (2)*(3) = 6, not in 4.

If you do not have a really good reason, *avoid* preprocessor macros. There are good reasons, but if something behaves like a function, better make it a function.

Now take a look at this:

```
template <class T>
inline T squareOf(const T& number)
{
    return number*number;
}
```

As inline, it does also replace code (at least if the compiler wants so), but here, this one actually behaves like a function (since it is one). Wouldn't expect a bad outcome from that one.

Comment: Got it thanks so much

Comment: Awesome explanation

Comment: @SrishtiMittal Edited my answer and added some more things.